# Excel Reference isn't valid for PivotTables RefreshTable

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a button that uses simple VBA to refresh pivot tables.

When I click it I am getting:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Reference isn't valid.

When I select `Debug` the following is highlighted:

> pt.RefreshTable

Full code:

```
Sub Refresh_pivot()

    Sheets("Control").Select
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
        
    Next ws
    
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Goto Reference:="returncell"
    Range("A15").Select
    
End Sub
```

Can anyone help explain the problem I have encountered?

Comment: Perhaps the source of the pivot table is no longer valid. Have you tried to manually click the refresh button when the relevant pivot table is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a pivot table referencing an ODBC data dump which had changed its external table name.

Updated the name and it worked again.